# Cordova build failed not sure why it is happening

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, gradle

All of my version are i think right but the build always fail please help me
i am sure that the java is perfect but not to sure about the android sdk
My gradle version Gradle 6.4
My adb version Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133

```
C:\Cordova\Hello>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=G:\Android sdk (cordova)\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\platform-tools (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: G:\Android sdk (cordova)\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\platform-tools
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Cordova\Hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Cordova\Hello\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Cordova\Hello\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be fixed in Android Studio. Open the SDK Manager, then go to the "SDK tools" tab and check "show package details". " Android SDK build tools " will be there. Check the box next to the Android SDK build tools 19.1.0 (or whatever number your error code is referencing) and hit 'Apply' to install.